# Page not aligning properly

Tags: css

So here is [the page](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame3).

I have set the editor to `display:inline-block;`

and also the svg to it as well. It works for this [page](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame) though.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is not aligning where?

Comment: The frame and editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the margin-left of your svg to *margin-left: 50px;* instead of *margin-left: 100px;*.

Comment: ah thank you. I can't believe I couldn't see this. I'm probably just a bit lazy.